# What familiar group is $G/H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

I'm stuck in a homework problem.

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, where $G = \Bbb Z_4 \oplus U(8)$ and $H =\langle (1, 3)\rangle$. What familiar group is $G/H?$

I know $H=\{(1,3),(2,1),(3,3),(0,1)\}$ and

$$G/H = \{gH : g \in G\}$$

which is $$\{(0,1)H , (0,3)H, (0,5) H, (0,7)H\}= \begin{align}\{ & (1,3),(2,1),(3,3),(0,1), \\
&(1,1),(2,3),(3,1),(0,3), \\
&(1,7),(2,5),(3,7),(0,5), \\
&(1,5),(2,7),(3,5),(0,7)\}.\end{align}$$

I cannot see what familiar group is this could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation to format your question

Comment: What do you mean by $U(8)$? I have seen this notation at few places, but don't know the exact meaning.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $G$ has $16$ elements and $H$ has four, which means that $G/H$ has four elements. That means you only have two options to choose from.

Comment: I'm still confused, could you give me more information please.

Comment: Which part of my hint is it that you're having trouble with? The fact that $G$ has 16 elements and $H$ has 4? The fact that this implies that $G/H$ has 4 elements? The fact that there are essentially only two groups of order 4? Or how one would distinguish between the two?

Comment: I understand how you get the number of cosets but besides U(8) and Z4, I cannot think of other groups of order 4 and those I've just said wouldn't work.

Comment: @AlineBellangero I can't see that you said that. Regardless, why do you say that $\Bbb Z_4$ doesn't work? Why do you say $U(8)$ doesn't work?